# How to create an ad hoc Wi-Fi network in OS X?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, wifi, ad-hoc

I came across a problem today  when there was a speaker in my class. The speaker was from the industry and had a company provided laptop which was not able to get connected to University network (some other problem which I had to raise in another question).

As a solution to the problem, I thought I would create the public Wi-Fi,
using my MacBook Pro, without a password so that he can get connected
directly. However I am a little embarrassed in not finding a option do so. Can anyone give me some solution if one exists.

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-up-an-ad-hoc-wireless-network.html 
Hint: use Google with "os x create ad hoc network"

Answer (score 2):

A solution does in fact exist. Click the Wi-Fi symbol in the menu bar and choose Create Network.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used that and had created one. _Unfortunately_ it doesn't offer the Internet.  As far I have learned its for your iPhone to be sync-ed over the wifi. I will be more than glad if it works as an access point for other devices to Internet. But I believe its not.

Comment: Sorry I missed the point of you question. After you've created your public Wi-Fi spot that way you need another means of connecting to the Uni network since you can't redistribute your Wi-Fi connection via the same Wi-Fi connection. So you're going to connect to the Uni network with an Ethernet cable at which point you might as well connect it directly to the provided laptop. I guess you could redistribute your Wi-Fi connection over Bluetooth and connect the laptop that way. Check what's available for you in the `Sharing` preference pane.

Comment: To do this on Big Sur, first check `WiFi, advanced, show legacy networks and options`.

Answer (score 0):

@Nikita was half right before you do that though giro Settings.app>sharing>internet sharing then select what you want to be shared and where it will be shared then create wifi network `meow`